# why I can't use array in initial state of react hook

Tags: reactjs, use-state

can I keep an array of state then update relative index? but neither of the following works, why?

```
const tempArray = new Array(studentFiltered.length).fill(false)
const [showDetail, setShowDetail] = useState(tempArray)
const [showDetail, setShowDetail] = useState(new Array(studentFiltered.length).fill(false))
const [showDetail, setShowDetail] = useState(tempArray.slice(0))
const [showDetail, setShowDetail] = useState([...tempArray])
const [showDetail, setShowDetail] = useState([].concat(tempArray))
const [showDetail, setShowDetail] = useState(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(tempArray)))
const [showDetail, setShowDetail] = useState(tempArray.map(value=>value))
const [showDetail, setShowDetail] = useState(tempArray.map(({...ele}) => {return ele}))
```

Comment: Works fine here, assuming there's a `studentFiltered.length`

Comment: I don't see any issue specifically, can you provide more context about what isn't working? Is there an error? What is happening versus what you expected?

Comment: Ty for so quick response, but showDetail can't get the initial value as I expected, showDetail initial value show empty array, I expect those are in tempArray all false with studentFiltered.length

Comment: Is `studentFiltered` initially also an empty array? In other words, is it passed as a prop and updated in a parent component in *some* subsequent render? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that includes all relevant code and how that code is updated.

Comment: sorry not sure how to show the sample code, studentFiltered is not empty, tempArray is an array with 25 "false" items, like my next comment but showDetail is [].

Comment: [
    false,
    false,
    false,
    false,
    false,
    false,
    false,
    false,
    false,
    false,
    false,
    false,
    false,
    false,
    false,
    false,
    false,
    false,
    false,
    false,
    false,
    false,
    false,
    false,
    false
]

Comment: It would be like the example snippet you already provided, but would be more complete. It would show us where `studentFiltered` is declared and how it's updated and passed to the component you are trying to use it in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TY all the comments, actually Is studentFiltered initially also an empty array? from Drew is the right direction, the usage of array is totally fine, my issue is because when component mounted, studentFiltered is empty.